# Autocoder in tensorflow. The loss does not go down

Tags: python, tensorflow

I do not understand why the loss does not change. The things I have tried:
changing number of layers in encode and decode according with the formula of dimensions, changing learning rate, changing optimization function, feeding both batch as images with no noise, changing batch size, checked the validity of input. The sample of output is provided below. This the entire code.

I am relatively new to the TensorFlow and it might something very silly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Network
tf.reset_default_graph()

noise_imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])

# Building the encoder
def encoder(x):
   out1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, [3, 3], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu) #26*26*32 
   out1pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=out1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2) #13*13*32
   out2 = tf.layers.conv2d(out1pool, 64, [3, 3], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu) #11*11*64
   out1pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=out2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2) #5*5*64

   flat_inputs = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(out1pool2)
   hundred = tf.layers.dense(flat_inputs, units=100)
   return hundred

   # Building the decoder
def decoder(x):
   img = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 10, 10, 1])

   l1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(img, 32, [7, 7], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu)
   l2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(l1, 1, [13, 13], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu)          
   return l2 

   # Construct model
   encoder_op = encoder(noise_imgs)
   decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op)

loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(imgs-decoder_op)))
optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001).minimize(loss)


# Start Training
noise_constant=0.2
num_iter = 1000
batch_size = 128

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

# Training
for i in range(num_iter):  
    batch_x, _ = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)

    #shape (64, 784)
    batch = batch_x.reshape([batch_size, 28, 28, 1])

    noise_matrix = noise_constant * np.random.randn(batch_size, 784)
    noise_matrix = noise_matrix.reshape([batch_size, 28, 28, 1])

    batch_img_noise = batch_x + noise_matrix
    batch_img_noise = batch_img_noise.reshape([64, 28, 28, 1])


    # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
     _, l = sess.run([optim, L], feed_dict={noise_imgs: batch_img_noise , imgs: batch})
   print(l)
```

The output:
152.3966
152.28357
152.38466
152.44324
152.20834
152.43982
152.36153
152.38193
152.28334
152.45685
152.28116
152.4884....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  #Network
tf.reset_default_graph()

noise_imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])

# Building the encoder
def encoder(x):
   out1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, [3, 3], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu) #26*26*32 
   out1pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=out1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2) #13*13*32
   out2 = tf.layers.conv2d(out1pool, 64, [3, 3], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu) #11*11*64
   out1pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=out2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2) #5*5*64

   flat_inputs = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(out1pool2)
   hundred = tf.layers.dense(flat_inputs, units=100)
   return hundred

   # Building the decoder
def decoder(x):
   img = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 10, 10, 1])

   l1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(img, 32, [7, 7], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu)
   l2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(l1, 1, [13, 13], padding="valid", activation=tf.nn.relu)          
   return l2 

   # Construct model
encoder_op = encoder(noise_imgs)
decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op)

loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(imgs-decoder_op)))
optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001).minimize(loss)


# Start Training
noise_constant=0.2
num_iter = 1000
batch_size = 128

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

# Training
for i in range(num_iter):  
    batch_x, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

    #shape (64, 784)
    batch = batch_x.reshape([batch_size, 28, 28, 1])

    noise_matrix = noise_constant * np.random.randn(batch_size, 784)
    noise_matrix = noise_matrix.reshape([batch_size, 28, 28, 1])

    batch_img_noise = batch + noise_matrix
    batch_img_noise = batch_img_noise.reshape([batch_size, 28, 28, 1])


    # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
    _, l = sess.run([optim, loss], feed_dict={noise_imgs: batch_img_noise , imgs: batch})
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print("Iter", i, ":", l)
```

I made a few changes in your code, like replace `L` with `loss`, to get it to run on my local machine.

It does converge:

```
Iter 0 : 105.12259
Iter 100 : 58.750557
Iter 200 : 46.29199
Iter 300 : 43.19689
Iter 400 : 39.70022
Iter 500 : 38.924805
Iter 600 : 36.81252
Iter 700 : 36.478275
Iter 800 : 37.10568
Iter 900 : 36.200474
```

You can visualise the output of the decoder using `matplotlib.pyplot` for a sanity check. I did, and it works.

However, you might want to consider changing your loss from `tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(imgs-decoder_op)))` to `tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(imgs-decoder_op))`.